# New wordpress install, what are the reasons the "Install Themes" tab is missing?

Tags: wp-admin

I just installed Wordpress 4.0.1 (never ran this version before, but I remember this not being a problem with older versions) and gave the requisite permissions to the various folders to allow updates.

But, logged in as admin, I still don't have an "Install Themes" tab like I see in all the tutorials.  I've been poking my way through the code, but don't have time any more so I figured I'd ask here, where is it doing the check to see whether or not to show the Install Themes tab?

---

<sup>Note, I installed Wordpress on Centos using YUM, not the normal download and unpack, I don't know why I did that other than it saved me a few clicks and caused me a few headaches</sup>

Answer (score 2):

One of possible reason is you/automated installation might have turned off installation of new themes and plugins in `wp-config.php`.

Make sure you do not have `DISALLOW_FILE_MODS` true in your `wp-config.php` file.

```
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true );
```

If it is then remove this line. Enabling this option in config file will disallow updates and installations of new themes and plugins from WordPress admin panel for security reasons.

You can read more about [`DISALLOW_FILE_MODS`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) on codex.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly my problem because I installed it via yum.  So, I'm guessing it was probably on for a reason then...

Comment: Actually that's added security. So you should turn it back on once you are done adding/editing themes and plugins.